# regex to capture optional group based on optional substring

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I want to create a regex to capture optional group based on optional substring. Examples could be:

```
DATEF[[%d/%m/%Y %H:%M 
DATEF[[%H:%M]]
DATEF
TIME
```

etc.

I would like the `DATE` and parameter `%H:%M` to be captured.
The expression `(.*?)\[\[(.*?)\]\]` works with parameters, but the optional excluded strings fail and return null.

Comment: The system is reformatting my original text. Lets try it this way. 
The string represents one of several functions with an optional parameter enclosed within --
For example, I want to capture 2 groups from the string: DATEF--%d/%m/%Y %H:%M-- 
into 2 groups. Group 1: DATEF 
and group 2: %d/%m/%Y %H:%M 
while ignoring --

If the string is DATEF only, then it retrieves the one group
If it is DATEF----, it could retrieve group 1

Comment: This expression isn't perfect, since it includes an additional group, but it does what I need. '(\w+)(\\[\\[.*?\\]\\])?'

Comment: FYI - stackoverflow encourages users to answer their own questions so that the question gets closed.

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest this one:

`/^([a-zA-Z]+)(?:\[\[([^\]]+)\]\])?$/`

group 1 holds the functionname, and if a `[[` is present, group 2 captures everything between `[[` and `]]`, if the squares are not present, group 2 won't be present at all.

**EDIT:**

Note the outer non-capturing group contains a capturing group:

```
/^([a-zA-Z]+)         #captures the command
    (?:\[\[           #matches, but not captures the opening brackets
        ([^\]]+?)     #captures the content of the brackets
    \]\])?            #matches the closing brackets
$/x
```

Comment: by using `?:` you made group2 not a capture group, meaning it can not be accessed AFAIK

Comment: inside the `[[]]` part is the real group 2, the outer `(?:)` group is just for the optional argument part grouping, but noone needs the suqare brackets to be captured

Comment: AFAIK `()` is a capture group, `(?:)` is a non-capture group. and optional group has a `?` at the end. like `()?` or `(?:)?`. and `[]` of any kind are not "groups" but "capture sets"

Comment: `[]` are character sets, but in general you are right. I am using an optional non-capturing group to match (if existent) the `[[%H:%M]]` part, within this non-capturing group there IS a capturing group, maybe you've overseen it as it is in between the outer square bracket pairs and the inner most char class

Comment: oh yes, you are right, i can see it now. i feel a bit silly now. but at least it was educational :)

Comment: actually it is hard to read, i am going to rework the expression in my Answer, so the capturing group can be seen more clearly